# python using selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriver

I'm trying to open the "digikey" website and use the search bar to send some data. Here's an example of the code but it looks like the send key is not working. I need help. Thank you.

```
import time
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/amuri/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0/site-packages/chromedriver.exe')
driver.implicitly_wait(3)

url ='https://www.digikey.com/'
driver.get(url)
print(driver.title)
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/header/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/input")
elem.click()
elem.send_keys("myString")
print(elem.text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For elem use `css` selector, not long xpath:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#main-layout-content .header__searchinput")
```

`header__searchinput` class is not unique, that's why I used `main-layout-content` id to as a parent.

Also add explicit wait:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=30)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#main-layout-content .header__searchinput")))
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#main-layout-content .header__searchinput")
elem.click()
elem.send_keys("myString")
```